# How to get specific text hyperlinks in the home webpage by BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to search all hyperlink that its text name includes "article" in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/
for example, on the bottom of this webpage

```
Write an Article
Improve an Article
```

I want to get them all hyperlink and print them, so I tried to,

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import re

url = 'https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/'

reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, "html.parser")
links = []
for link in soup.findAll('a',href = True):
    #print(link.get("href")

    if re.search('/article$', href):
        links.append(link.get("href"))
```

However, it get a [] in result, how to solve it?

Comment: Hi, do you have part of your html so we can reproduce your code? That would make it easier to debug and help you with your question.

Comment: @3dSpatialUser check it again, please

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because provided code do not lead to your issue with empty `ResultSet`, there are several other issues (module, variables) - Just a hint: If you wanna find article in text, why are you searching in href?

Comment: @HedgeHog the hyperlink's name is "article" in website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you can try:
Note that there are more links with the test `article` in the link you provided, but it gives the idea how you can deal with this.

In this case I just checked if the word `article` is in the text of that tag. You can use regex search there, but for this example it is an overkill.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/'
res = requests.get(url)

if res.status_code != 200:
    'no resquest'

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "html.parser")

links_with_article = soup.findAll(lambda tag:tag.name=="a" and "article" in tag.text.lower())
```

EDIT:

If you know that there is a word in the href, i.e. in the link itself:

```
soup.select("a[href*=article]")
```

this will search for the word `article` in the `href` of all elements `a`.

Edit: get only href:

```
hrefs = [link.get('href') for link in links_with_article]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's the thing I want, but it return all info, how can I only get hype?like,results = soup.findAll(zone_links.get("href"))

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: Thank you so much, I still have a little question, how can I use regex to rewrite it? I mean, for example "4article", "5article"... I write  re.match ("/darticle$", tag.text.lower()) why not true?

Comment: Your `/d` should be `\d`. For example you can use: `links_with_article = soup.findAll(lambda tag:tag.name=="a" and re.search(r'\darticle',  tag.text.lower()))` to find the article. I used search to search the whole string, match searched only from the start of the string.

Comment: Thanks for your help again and I really appreciate it!